# How to toggle 2 variables on bind keydown in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’ve got a text input and a textarea.
When I type some texts in “input” and hit “enter” key, I want these texts to go to the textarea **with different classes** for each time, first I’ve tried “toggle”, but didn’t seem to work. Is there a better way to achieve  this?

Here is my code so far:

```
$('#input').bind('keydown', function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val() != ''){
    event.preventDefault();
    var str1 = $('#textarea').val() + '<p class="a">' + $(this).val() + '</p>';
    var str2 = $('#textarea').val() + '<p class="b">' + $(this).val() + '</p>';
    $('#texarea').val( str1 );
// how to make str1 to str2 on next keydown? like toggle?
    $(this).val('')
    }
```

});

EXPECTATIONS:

Hit enter, txts on input value goes to textarea with “p” warp around, and this p has class a or b differently when next enter key down.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Store `a` or `b` in a variable outside of the binding.  When the event happens, use it for the class, and then logically flip it's value to the other class.

Comment: Also as a side note, avoid usages of `$(this).val()` and `$(this).val('')`.  `this.value` is already a directly accessable property on the element.  There is no need to construct a jQuery object to then use a library method to change the value, when it is already directly accessable.

Comment: Similar to above - use a flag if flag true class=a else class=b then flag = !flag

Comment: ^ Oh, yeah, true/false would make it easier.

Comment: Thank you @Taplar , as an new one to Javascript, I need some times to process, thank you for advice about $(this) and true / false, I'm going to modify my codes to make it better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Taplar!
After my unremitting efforts and @Taplar's help, I finally succeeded!

here is what I've got:

```
    var bool;
    $('#input').bind('keydown', function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13 && $(this).val() != ''){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (bool == true || bool == null ){ classs='me' };
    if (bool == false) { classs='you' };
    var str = $('#textarea').val() + '<div class="fdia"><div class="avatar '+ classs +'"></div><div class="dialog '+ classs +'">' + $(this).val() + '</div></div>\n';
    $('#textarea').val( str );
    $(this).val('');
    if(bool == false){ bool = true }else{ bool = false };
}
```

});

This "bool" guy will be given true or false each time the function execute, so next time will be different.

About "$('this')" issue, it needs more work, I will handle it later...